# Make PC "administrative server" on home network, Windows 10

Tags: networking, windows-10, administrator

I'm helping a family member setup their home network to comply with their workplace IT security requirements. One of the requirements is that his PC must be the "administrative server" on the network that is not accessible from other things on the network. Does anyone know what "administrative server" means? It sounds like I just need to make sure his computer doesn't show up in my network places, but I'm not sure. Does anyone have some ideas?

Comment: Is this for AD or Citrix Remote Desktop?  A "server" has permission to listen to make additonal connections from a remote host, with suitable Apps to look on certain IP ports like FTP (21/22) while a "client" can request a connection thru firewall and App. This can be done by any user in the Administrator Group, such as the primary user as opposed to a "limited guest account"

Comment: As far as I know it's just straightforward Windows home network. His PC should be able to get onto the network and use services like network printing, but other machines on the network should not be able to access anything related to his PC.

Comment: LAN sharing on WAN is off by default.

Comment: It’s simple: There is no such thing as an “administrative server”. The IT security policy is probably full of BS, as one might expect. What I *think* they want is simple: The work PC must be completely isolated from the regular home network. This isn’t something that can be easily achieved with consumer hardware. Any chance you can provide the original text in the policy document?

Comment: Hey Daniel, assuming that your assumption is correct, what kind of solutions are out there?

Comment: Open source router firmware like OpenWrt or a professional router. Unfortunately, without knowing the exact text, I cannot tell what exactly is required.